# getting many rows with many ids

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
Action_set
id_action_p1 | id_action_p2 | id_action_p3 | etc. 
1            | 1            | 2
2            | 3            | 1
1            | 1            | 1

Action
id_action | id_type | value
1         | 0       | NULL
2         | 1       | NULL
3         | 2       | NULL
```

Where `id_action_p1/2/3` in `Action_set` table are fks to `id_action` of `Action` table.

For each id of a row in `Action_set` I need to get the respective row in `Action`.

For example, lets get the first row of Action_set:

```
(id_action_p1 | id_action_p2 | id_action_p3 )
1 | 1 | 2
```

must give me as result:

```
(id_type | value)
0 | NULL
0 | NULL
1 | NULL
```

I'm noob with mysql, so no idea how to do :(

**Edit:** here my tables (**ignore id_lap**)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Action` (
  `id_action` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_action`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `Action` (`id_action`, `value`, `id_type`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 0),
(2, NULL, 1),
(3, NULL, 2),
(4, NULL, 3),
(5, NULL, 4),
(6, NULL, 5);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Action_set` (
  `id_action_set` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_lap` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_parent_action_set` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_pu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_action_p8` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_stage` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_action_set`),
  KEY `fk_Action_set_Lap` (`id_lap`),
  KEY `fk_Action_set_Action_set1` (`id_parent_action_set`),
  KEY `fk_pu` (`id_action_pu`),
  KEY `fk_p1` (`id_action_p1`),
  KEY `fk_p2` (`id_action_p2`),
  KEY `fk_p3` (`id_action_p3`),
  KEY `fk_p4` (`id_action_p4`),
  KEY `fk_p5` (`id_action_p5`),
  KEY `fk_p6` (`id_action_p6`),
  KEY `fk_p7` (`id_action_p7`),
  KEY `fk_p8` (`id_action_p8`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11;

INSERT INTO `Action_set` (`id_action_set`, `id_lap`, `id_parent_action_set`, `id_action_pu`, `id_action_p1`, `id_action_p2`, `id_action_p3`, `id_action_p4`, `id_action_p5`, `id_action_p6`, `id_action_p7`, `id_action_p8`, `id_stage`) VALUES
(1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 2, 2, 0),
(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0),
(3, 1, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 4, 4, 1),
(4, 1, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(5, 1, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 1, 1, 2),
(6, 1, 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2),
(7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0),
(8, 1, 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 4, 4, 1),
(9, 1, 8, 4, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(10, 1, 9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 2);
```

---

**Edit 2**

Hello guys, I found this solution, that return exactly as expected:

```
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p1 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p2 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p3 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p4 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p5 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p6 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p7 AND id_action_set = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_type, value FROM Action, Action_set WHERE id_action = id_action_p8 AND id_action_set = 1
```

There is how to optimize it?

Comment: How are your keys defined? Can you add the create tables SQL?

Comment: your table Action_set looks weird. why do you have three rows with Foreign keys? and none for Primary

Comment: @nischayn22 it was just an example. Check out my edit.

Comment: Thanks, can you restate how you need the query to work now that I can see your full structure? I am trying to find out what key you are wanting to use to fetch the data from the table. Looking at your tables it looks like you may want to use id_action_set but I would like to fully understand so I can give you the query

Comment: @Jeremy i renamed the columns names, check if you can understand better. I have no clue how to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_type, value from Action where id_action in 
(select id_p1 as id from Action_set limit 0,1 union all
 select id_p2 as id from Action_set limit 0,1 union all
 select id_p3 as id from Action_set limit 0,1)
```

I am sure there exists better ways to do this, but this works too.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you want to use the actual tables data, this gave me the result you were looking for.

**With a defined action_set**

```
SELECT id_type, value
FROM action
    LEFT JOIN action_set ON (id_action = id_action_set)
WHERE id_action_set = 1
```

It would help to update your original post to use the actual table data fields to get a more accurate response. Hopefully this will help you get a push in the right direction. Since you are using FKs the LEFT JOIN above is almost useless (assuming you have it updating on change). I just need more info to give you the proper query. Unless someone else already understand what you are trying to accomplish... I'm still a little lost.

** All action_set's**

```
SELECT id_type, value
FROM action
    LEFT JOIN action_set ON (id_action = id_action_set)
```

** all action_set's with the id_action** 
Since the id_action = id_action_set

```
SELECT id_action, id_type, value
FROM ACTION
    LEFT JOIN action_set ON ( id_action = id_action_set )
```

Am I correct in assuming the id_action = id_action_set
I do not have your FKs in the provided SQL so I am only assuming

Comment: that does not gave me the expected result. For each id of each column of `Action_set`, I need to get the proper `Action` row.

Comment: I just saw you updated your post. Let me read it and I'll update this post with what I can figure out

Comment: It looks like the post above me has the best solution for how the tables are structured.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `Action` results in separate columns like so:

```
SELECT
    a.*
    b.id_type AS p1_type, b.value AS p1_value,
    c.id_type AS p2_type, c.value AS p2_value,
    d.id_type AS p3_type, d.value AS p3_value
FROM
    Action_set a
INNER JOIN
    Action b ON a.id_action_p1 = b.id_action
INNER JOIN
    Action c ON a.id_action_p2 = c.id_action
INNER JOIN
    Action d ON a.id_action_p3 = d.id_action
```

That would give you a result set along the lines of:

```
id_p1 | id_p2 | id_p3 | p1_type | p1_value | p2_type | p2_value | p3_type | p3_value
1     | 1     | 2     | 0       | NULL     | 0       | NULL     | 1       | NULL
...
...
```

That would be an ideal solution, but if you need the result to be in rows, you could do:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT aa.*, bb.id_type, bb.value
        FROM Action_set aa
        INNER JOIN Action bb ON aa.id_action_p1 = bb.id_action

        UNION ALL

        SELECT aa.*, bb.id_type, bb.value
        FROM Action_set aa
        INNER JOIN Action bb ON aa.id_action_p2 = bb.id_action

        UNION ALL

        SELECT aa.*, bb.id_type, bb.value
        FROM Action_set aa
        INNER JOIN Action bb ON aa.id_action_p3 = bb.id_action
    ) a
ORDER BY
    a.id_action_p1,
    a.id_action_p2,
    a.id_action_p3,
    a.id_type
```

That would give you a result set like:

```
id_action_p1 | id_action_p2 | id_action_p3 | id_type | value
1            | 1            | 2            | 0       | NULL
1            | 1            | 2            | 0       | NULL
1            | 1            | 2            | 1       | NULL
```